# Control Android TV box via Android phones/tablets

Tags: remote-control, android-tv

I have a T95m Android TV box which is fantastic. I am trying to find out if there are apps I can use on another Android device and have that device act as a remote (keyboard, mouse, and touch functions).

I plan on installing this app on Samsung Galaxy S5, S6, S7, Acer A500, and hopefully a new Android tablet in the coming days.

Answer (score 1):

[Android TV Remote Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tv.remote)
by Google Inc can be downloaded for free from Google Play Store. It lets you control your Android TV by directional pads, touch pad, virtual keyboard as well as your device's microphone.

Other than that I only know of manufacturer specific apps like Sony's Video & TV Sideview for example. But I'm not sure any of those would work with your t95m TV box.

Comment: Hi, note that the app is now not available on the Play Store anymore (you may still be able to see the entry on the Play Store if you have installed it before).